# All requests via Proxy in Node-Webkit

Tags: node.js, authentication, proxy, request, node-webkit

Is there a way to force Node-webkit to use proxied settings for all requests ? I know there is an API solution using `setProxyConfig()` but this doesn't work with authenticated proxy, the prompt shows up to login but crash when submitted...

So I tried to use node `request` module, and it works fine :

```
var request=require('request');
var proxy = request.defaults({'proxy':'http://login:pwd@proxy:port'});
```

But now my problem is to tell node-webkit to use this for each request.
Any solutions ?

I'm quite new using node and node-webkit so maybe there is a better way to do that.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
process.env.http_proxy = 'http://login:pwd@proxy:port'
```

It will work with `request` lib, also should impact other requests from node-webkit (assets, ajax)

But may be other libraries don't use environment proxy settings. If that doesn't work you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either.. But thanks.
Anyway I found the cause of app crash when using ``setProxyConfig()``, it was timeout in AJAX request.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is solved, but i came up with a simple solution:

i wrote a simple wrapper for the request library
https://gist.github.com/jodevsa/7dd9662b8244359fa0d7626ae7c9bd69

all you have to do is ,

1. Head to $PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/request/
2. Rename index.js to core.js
3. Create a new file called index.js
4. Copy code content from the above gist link to index.js
5. Change proxyLoc value to you'r preferred proxy

If you decided to disable proxy , just change value of ON variable to false inside index.js

Cheers :D